# Transaction in cakephp- 3.0

Tags: sql, cakephp, transactions, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

In my cakephp3.0 application registration page the registration data is inserting into two tables. I am using query builder for doing this.  After the successful insertion of data into the first table(Projects table) projectId(primary key of Projects table which is auto incremented value) will return and which is used to insert into second table that is ProjectCustomers table, in projectCustomers table projectId is used as forign key. My controller look like this

```
public function initialize() {
parent::initialize();    
$this->Project = new ProjectsTable();
$this->ProjectCustomer = new ProjectCustomersTable();
```

}

```
public function add() {  
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
  $project_id = $this->Project->putProject($formData['survey_id'], $formData['title'], $formData['operator'], $this->Auth->user('id'));
  $this->ProjectCustomer->putProjectCustomer($project_id, $formData['air_id'], $formData['email'], $formData['name'], $formData['company_name'], $formData['department_name'], SYS_ADMIN, PROJECT_CUSTOMER_STATUS_ACTIVE, $date, $date);
  return $this->redirect(['action' => 'view', $project_id]);
}
```

}

What I need is that I want to make this two insertion action in a transaction so that if second insertion is failed anyhow, the first insertion in Projects table should roll back. Thank in advance for the help...

Comment: Why don't you use the proper functionality that CakePHP provides, ie the ORMs ability to automatically save data including associations? Also instantiating table classes manually usually isn't an overly good idea.

Comment: As I am doing an application porting  and I have a requirement to do this way  I am not able to follow save method. Any way as cakephp3.0 is supporting query builder  there might be some option to do transaction for this also right?